# java.util.Base64 does not work for Android version below 8.0

Tags: java, android, base64

Base 64 string creation using java.util.Base64 is different than creation with android.util.Base6. I need the one that is created by using java.util.Base64 but this does not work for Android version below 8.0. How can I make this work for below 8.0 or is there any alternate?

Currently, I have wrapped this with a version number that if it's not 8.0 then run the code.

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= `enter code here`android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(messageDigest);
        }

I want the same output that I get with java.util.Base64 even for below android version 8.0.

Comment: If you already tried that solution and you think this is not a duplicate write here and I will re-open the question.

Comment: I have tried that solution but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Ok, I've re-opened the question